# Is it possible to solve N-body problem if only one body is moving and all other are static?

Tags: integration, physics, mathematical-physics

We have an N bodies which gravitates with another body. Only that one body is moving and all N bodies are static.

Is it possible to calculate analytically the moving body trajectory in this case?

Comment: My guess is that this does not help.

Comment: @Peter I feel that this is possible. We can split the problem into multiple 2-body problems and then combine solutions somehow.

Comment: This question is likely better suited for https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How are the $N-1$ other bodies static? Are they held in place by other forces? Or are you imagining the unlikely configuration where all but one mass is at equilibrium?

Answer (score 1):

Already Euler solved the problem of computing the orbit of a body moving in the gravitational field from two fixed masses; see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_three-body_problem).

With more than two fixed masses I don't know the answer, but I suspect that it's not an integrable system anymore (except perhaps for very particular configurations of the masses).

Comment: Is it poority of our math?

Comment: @Robotex: It's rather that “reality” is usually too chaotic and complicated to be described by explicit solution formulas (as Poincaré realized).